# Direction of movement sun with respect to the NGP

Tags: milky-way, coordinate

When viewed from above, i.e., looking down from the North Galactic Pole towards the South Galactic Pole, does the sun rotate clockwise or counterclockwise around the Galactic center?

Comment: Related: [In which direction does the Milky Way rotate?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21450/in-which-direction-does-the-milky-way-rotate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Backer and Sramek 1999](https://doi.org/10.1086/307857)
observed that relative to more distant radio sources, the galactic center
[Sgr A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*)
had a heliocentric [proper motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_motion)
of about -6 milliarcseconds per year in galactic longitude.
[Reid et al. 1999](https://doi.org/10.1086/307855)
reported a similar result.
Looking from NGP to SGP,
[galactic longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system)
increases counterclockwise, a decrease in longitude is a clockwise motion, and the Sun revolves clockwise around the galactic center.